# Flowers Challenge on HackerRank

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I worked through the [Flowers](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flowers) challenge on hackerrank.com and would like to get feedback on solution and algorithm implementation.  It was suggested by hackerrank to review greedy algorithm to solve this challenge.  As far as I understand this is an implementation of greedy algorithm.

> You and your \$K−1\$ friends want to buy \$N\$ flowers. Flower number \$i\$ has cost \$c_i\$. Unfortunately the seller does not want just one customer to buy a lot of flowers, so he tries to change the price of flowers for customers who have already bought some flowers. More precisely, if a customer has already bought \$x\$ flowers, he should pay \$(x+1) \times c_i\$ dollars to buy flower number \$i\$.
>
> You and your \$K−1\$ friends want to buy all \$N\$ flowers in such a way that you spend the least amount of money. You can buy the flowers in any order.
>
> ### Input:
>
> The first line of input contains two integers \$N\$ and \$K\$ (\$K≤N\$). The next line contains \$N\$ space separated positive integers \$c_1,c_2,\dots,c_N\$.
>
> ### Output:
>
> Print the minimum amount of money you (and your friends) have to pay in order to buy all \$N\$ flowers.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Flowers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <Integer> flowerPriceList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int numFlowers = sc.nextInt();
        int numFriends = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i<numFlowers;i++){
            flowerPriceList.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        // Sort the ArrayList in reverse order to start bying flowers from most expensive
        Collections.sort(flowerPriceList,Collections.reverseOrder());
        int flowersBought = 0;
        int friendNum = 0;
        int total = 0;
        for(int price:flowerPriceList){
            //itterate throught all the flower prices and calculate the total
            total +=(flowersBought+1)*price;
            friendNum++;
            if(friendNum == numFriends){
                //if all friends bought flowers reset the friend counter and restart the cycle
                friendNum = 0;
                flowersBought++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Class name and general comments

Your class is named `Flowers` but there is a comment here that says:

```
/* (...) Your class should be named Solution. */
```

Although I think that `Flowers` is a much better name, personally.

Generally, I understood your code better than the assignment description, so well done there.

#### Array instead of ArrayList

Instead of using an `ArrayList <Integer>`, that by the way would be better to declare as `List<Integer>` (use interface for declaration, implementation for initialization), you could use an `int[]` instead, as you know the exact size of the list. There's no need to do any dynamical resizing of the list, so a `int[]` would be just fine.

#### Small spacing nitpick

A little nitpick would be to use a bit more spacing, I am a bit allergic to lines like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<numFlowers;i++){
```

better would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numFlowers; i++) {
```

And also:

```
total +=(flowersBought+1)*price;
```

becomes:

```
total += (flowersBought + 1) * price;
```

#### Closing statement

Again, your code was very readable and your approach is good, and indeed it is a greedy algorithm

As said on Hackerrank:

> A greedy algorithm is an algorithm that follows the problem-solving heuristic of making the locally optimal choice at each stage with the hope of finding a global optimum.

This is indeed what your code does. It always picks a way to buy the flower in the cheapest way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   This is really helpful info.  Helps me get better.  The requirements for hackerrank solutons that the classes are name Solution so they can run it.  I definitely have to watch the spacing.  Makes the code neater and more readable.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Comment by [@spyr03](/users/58248/spyr03):

> you can replace the check `friendNum == numFriends` with `friendNum = (friendNum + 1) % numFriends`

Comment: @spyr03 If you care to repost this answer under your own name, we can delete this placeholder.